# How do i get words from rows and columns having letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x

doing an assignment and struck to this problem

```
def board_contains_word(board, word):
    '''(list of list of str, str) -> bool

    Return True if and only if word appears in board.

    Precondition: board has at least one row and one column.

    >>> board_contains_word([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 'ANT')
    True
    '''
 return word in board
```

but i am getting  `FALSE`

Thanks in  advance

Comment: So are you trying to see if the word appears in a row or are you trying to see if the word appears somewhere in the board like a cross-word puzzle?  Just checking `word in board` shouldn't work either way, but you'll really need to be more clear if you want an intelligible answer.

Comment: To add to @BenTrofatter's comment, do diagonals need to be matched? How about backwards words (e.g. a row that is `['T', 'N', 'A']`)?

Comment: At a minimum, you'll need to manually check to see if any sublist contains all the letters of the word in the proper order. If you also have to check if any column of letters contains the letters, then that will have to be done as a separate pass though the board data and likewise for diagonals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python `in` operator works a bit differently from how you're using it. Here are some examples:

```
>>> 'laughter' in 'slaughter'
True
>>> 1 in [1,6,5]
True
>>> 'eta' in ['e','t','a']
False
>>> 'asd' in ['asdf','jkl;']
False
>>>
```

As you can see, it's got two major uses: testing to see if a string can be found in another string, and testing to see if an element can be found in an array. Also note that the two uses can't be combined.

Now, about solving your problem. You'll need some sort of loop `for` going through all of the rows one by one. Once you've picked out a single row, you'll need some way to `join` all of the array elements together. After that, you can figure out if the word is `in` the board.

Note: this only solves the problem of searching horizontally. Dunno if that's the whole assignment. You can adapt this method to searching vertically using the `zip` function.

Comment: The code you have posted was my actual problem.
This works better for me..Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to get you unstuck:

```
def board_contains_word(board, word):
    # check accross
    for row in board:
        return word in ''.join(row):

    # try with board's rows and columns transposed
    for row in zip(*board):
        return word in ''.join(row):

    return False

print board_contains_word([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 'ANT')
print board_contains_word([['A', 'N', 'T', 'T'], ['X', 'S', 'O', 'B']], 'TO')
```

Hint: You could simplify things by using the `any()` function.

Comment: FYI you can use `zip(*board)` which will work with all board sizes.

Comment: BTW, the `list` call is unnecessary. `for` loops are smart enough to unpack generators without them.

Comment: @NickODell: OK, removed. Obviously I'm no Py 3 virtuoso.

Comment: Thanks @martineau and Nick ODell...for sharing your great knowledge which helped me alot in solving my problem.